# Folding a tuple in Scala 3

Tags: scala, implicit, zio

Working with ZIO and Scala 3, I want to create a utility function `productElementsLayer` that for a given type `A <: Product` produces a value of type `ZLayer[A, Nothing, (E1, ..., EN)` where `(E1, ..., EN)` is the tuple representation of the product (e.g. case class).

So I wrote the following prototype code:

```
import zio.*
import scala.deriving.Mirror

case class AppConfig(
  foo: String,
  bar: Int
)

val appConfig: AppConfig = ???

val productof = summon[Mirror.ProductOf[AppConfig]]

trait Layerize[In] {
  type Out
  def apply(a: In): ZLayer[Any, Nothing, Out]
}

object Layerize {
  type Aux[In, Out0] = Layerize[In] { type Out = Out0 }
}

implicit val layerizeEmptyTuple: Layerize.Aux[EmptyTuple, Any] = {
  e => ZLayer.empty
}

implicit def layerizeNonEmptyTuple[Head: Tag, Tail <: Tuple, TailOut: Tag](
  implicit tailLayerize: Layerize.Aux[Tail, TailOut]
): Layerize.Aux[Head *: Tail, Head & TailOut] = {
   case head *: tail => ZLayer.succeed(head) ++ tailLayerize(tail)
}

val res = summon[Layerize[productof.MirroredElemTypes]].apply(productof.fromProduct(appConfig))
```

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to get the implicits working, as I get the following error:

```
No given instance of type Layerize[productof.MirroredElemTypes] was found for parameter x of method summon in object Predef.
...
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JY92ZnCCT5ynEjtMFbIvyg

This is pretty much how I would have solved it in Scala 2 (except also using shapeless Lazy).
But Scala 3 seems to work differently.
So how do I get this working?

Comment: Your question feels ill-formed: what are you trying to achieve ? Are you trying to write Scala 3 code ? If so, why are there `implicit`s everywhere ?

Comment: @t9dupuy implicits are still valid syntax in Scala 3. I attempted the new syntax with the same results. And I have very clearly stated what I want to achieve in my question.

Comment: Try calling `layerizeNonEmptyTuple` directly, you most likely find that you mistyped something, and so compiler cannot prove the existence of `Tag[Head]` or `Tag[TailOut]` or  perhaps the `layerizeEmptyTuple` of bad `Out` type. You can just pass tuples as the type of e.g `summon[Layerize[(String, Int)]]` to make debugging faster. E.g `layerizeNonEmptyTuple[String, Int *: EmptyTuple, Int & Any]`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, @MateuszKubuszok, but unfortunately manual creation works just fine:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wWUmA8wCR3WZmsrRmtZeYQ